# Negative Lookahead Regex is ignoring my sentence

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I'm trying to get N group in the following text using this Regex `N+(?!\d+N)`

```
20NNN (Expected Result: NN)
2NNN  (Expected Result: NN)
2000NNNN (Expected Result: NNN)
```

When I execute the code, the Regex fails.

PS: The N group after number+N could be any quantity.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `N+(?!\d+N)` pattern matches an `N` char, one or more occurrences, that is not immediately followed with 1+ digits and `N`.

You may use

```
(?<=\dN)N+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LmHLD8/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=\dN)` - a location immediately preceded with any digit and `N`
- `N+` - one or more `N` chars.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you bro, you rock man ! I learned something new today !